# Permission denied ssl.log in python

Tags: python, web-services, ssl

I tried to exploit an webservice like this :" https://api.androidhive.info/contacts/ " by using `urllib.request.urlopen`. And to Ignore SSL certificate errors i using some thing learned from Coursera like this:

```
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
```

But when launch file, i got an error at line `ctx = ssl.create_default_context()`. They said that "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\Admin\Documents\ssl.log'"
How can i fix it ? Thanks!

Comment: sorry, i cant install certifi, can you show me how to install it ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have the environment variable `SSLKEYLOGFILE` set to `C:\Users\Admin\Documents\ssl.log` but that you don't have the access permissions to actually write to this file. The behavior to automatically use this environment variable from inside `ssl.create_default_context()` was added with recent Python versions. From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.create_default_context):

> When keylog_filename is supported and the environment variable SSLKEYLOGFILE is set, create_default_context() enables key logging.

If you want to use SSL key logging then make sure to set the variable to a path where you can actually write to. If you don't want to have such logging unset the variable, for example by using `del os.environ['SSLKEYLOGFILE']` before calling `ssl.create_default_context()`.